# Añadir value a class html (jquery --> html)

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente código en la página principal de HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <title>Dynamic Bar - Web server</title>
    
        <style>
            html,* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
            html { background-color: #fafafa; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed'; }
            .container { margin: 150px auto; max-width: 960px; }
            h1 { margin: 150px auto 50px auto;text-align: center;}
            p { text-align: center; }
          </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <script src="jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript.js"></script>
    
        <div class="Dynamic_chart">
            <ul class="numbers">
                <li><span>10</span></li>
                <li><span>5</span></li>
                <li><span>0</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="bars">
                <li><div class="bar" data-plc="10"></div><span>Press. 1</span></li>
                <li><div class="bar" data-plc="10"></div><span>Press. 2</span></li>
                <li><div class="bar" data-plc="10"></div><span>Press. 3</span></li>
                <li><div class="bar" data-plc="10"></div><span>Press. 4</span></li>
                <li><div class="bar" data-plc="10"></div><span>Press. 5</span></li>
                <li><div class="bar" data-plc="10"></div><span>Press. 6</span></li>
                <li><div class="bar" data-plc="10"></div><span>Press. 7</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Estoy ejecutando la librería de script *jquery*, y otro script para la actualización, lectura de datos en el HTML. El código del script que me actualiza estos datos:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

    let pressures = [,,,,,,];
    let temperatures = [,,,,,];
    let counter ;
    let testconvert = 0;

    setInterval(function() {


        $.get("press1.html", function(result){

            pressures[0] = parseInt(result, 10);
        })

     
        $(function(){

            $('.bars li .bar').each(function(key, bar){

                var plc = $(this).data('plc');

                $(this).data('plc').text(pressures[0].trim());

                $(this).animate({
                    'height' : pressures[0]
                })

            })

            console.log("Script ejecutado XXXXX");
            console.log(pressures[0]);
        })

    },1000);
})
```

Lo que quiero hacer es escribir el valor de cada `data-plc="10"` por el valor de una variable en JavaScript

```
<li><div class="bar" data-plc="10"></div><span>Press. 1</span></li>
```

Por ejemplo:

```
let pressure = 20;
<li><div class="bar" data-plc="20"></div><span>Press. 1</span></li>
```

El dato que tengo en "*pressure*" sea cargado en `data-plc=" "`.

Comment: Mírate [attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) de jquery para eso, o bien [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) de javascript

Comment: Le hace falta mucho contexto a tu pregunta, de donde se manda el valor que quieres poner en el atributo **data-plc=""**, de un **Input**, un **select** o estará declarada esa variable en tu código?. Modifica tu pregunta y explícate mejor para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según comprendo quieres esto:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    let pressure = 10;

    $(".bar").each(function(i){
        $(".bar").attr("data-plc",pressure);
    })
    alert('Todos los div con clase "bar" han sido modificados con el valor de pressure "'+pressure+'".')
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Pagina que cambia el atributo de un elenmto tomando valor de variable JQuery</h4>

    <ul class="bars">
        <li><div class="bar" data-plc=""></div><span>Press. 1</span></li>
        <li><div class="bar" data-plc=""></div><span>Press. 2</span></li>
        <li><div class="bar" data-plc=""></div><span>Press. 3</span></li>
        <li><div class="bar" data-plc=""></div><span>Press. 4</span></li>
        <li><div class="bar" data-plc=""></div><span>Press. 5</span></li>
        <li><div class="bar" data-plc=""></div><span>Press. 6</span></li>
        <li><div class="bar" data-plc=""></div><span>Press. 7</span></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Inspecciona el elemento y tendrán el valor de la variable **pressure**, dime si te ayudo.

Answer (score 0):

> No piensen que quiero todo fácil, también consulto información e investigo y a veces la falta de experiencia no me ayuda a saber qué necesito buscar.

El caso es que efectivamente funcionó el comando de atributo:

```
$('.bars li .bar1').each(function(){

$(this).css({"height" : pressures[0]});
$('.bars .bar1').attr("data-plc", pressures[0]);
```

Comment: Los agradecimientos se dan _con votos a favor_. Pulsá en [edit] para mejorar tu respuesta: _¿qué hace este código?_ Además, no olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) la respuesta que te fue más útil. Por último, si querés conocer el funcionamiento del sitio (no, no es un foro), no olvides hacer el [tour].